# twitter integration in C# error

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I want to integrate twitter in my ASP.Net web site with C# . I want to implement a profile page in which user should be able to sign in from twitter. After clicking on "Sign Up via Twitter" Button. I have made a twitter application and i am doing this thing with OAuth. After getting user details i want to add them to my SQL Server Database(So that in future user can sign in using these details).
IT gives an exception at runtime.The exception is

The remote server returned an  error:(403) Forbidden.so please answer if you have done this kind of stuff.

I have already search all around on the internet,am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is the twitter end point you are trying to connect in your api?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

This will let the application use the credentials of the logged in user to access the site. If it's returning 403, clearly it's expecting authentication.

It's also possible that you (now?) have an authenticating proxy in between you and the remote site. In which case, try:

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Hope this helps.